# Correct way to run a program

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, symbolic-link

I've got a program called OOMMF and i run it by simply cd in the directory oommf and from here i run the executable oommf.tcl , but I'd like a way to run it from everywhere, is it correct to add the directory where my program is placed to the $PATH? or is there a more correct way ? like maybe a symbolic link? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a link to the application in /usr/local/bin or ~/.local/bin (which are already in $PATH): Something like `ln /path/to/oommf.tcl /usr/local/bin/oommf`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, i think the problem is maybe that this oommf.tcl file needs the other files that are in its directory